# passing multiple arguments via mapply to a formula function

Tags: r

I would like to run two loess regressions. The data is provided as a list which contains two elements. Each element itself contains a pair of columns (x and y for regression) for which I would like to run the loess regression. I would like to do so by employing the apply family specifically maply. However loess regression takes the formula expression y ~ x and I believe you can not directly reference for x and y in the formula format as you would for a non formula function where the variables could be provided via mapply.

```
X <- c(3,4,3,2,3,4,5,6,7,7,6,5,4,3,3,5,3,6,3,5,6,3,6,3,4,5,5,4,3,4,5,3,5,5,4)
Y <- c(3,2,1,3,4,2,1,2,3,5,4,3,2,1,1,3,4,5,6,7,6,5,4,3,2,3,4,3,4,2,4,3,NA,NA,NA)

mydata<-data.frame(X,Y)

L <- seq(1:length(mydata))
n <- function(x) length(na.omit(mydata[,x]))
n <- lapply(L,n)

# sequence each (Variable time)
x <- function(x) seq(1:n[[x]])
x <- lapply(L,x)
y <- function(x) na.omit(mydata[,x])
y <- lapply(L,y)

# create a list with pairs of columns each 
Data <- function (p) data.frame(y[[p]], x[[p]])
Data <- lapply(L,Data)

# In a writen function you would do (where p will correspond to the sequence of L and d is the number of columns in each element) and use mapply passing the arguments 

d <- seq(1:length(mydata))
p <- seq(1:length(Data))
W1<-expand.grid(p=p,d=d)

# However the formula framework y ~ x for loess does not allow to pass multiple variable arguments to x and y and use mapply to do so which I would like to do as to automate this process. I wrote in the same format as x and y variables will be passed to a non formula function which does not work.     

mapply(function(p,d) ((y ~ x, span = 0.75, degree = 2,parametric = FALSE, drop.square = FALSE, normalize = FALSE,family = c("gaussian")),W1$p,W1$d)
```

I am wondering how could I pass using the mapply function the different variables to the loess function.

Comment: I guess your functional specification is not right

Comment: It's very unclear to me what you expect as your desired output. Do you want to run a loess regression for each data.frame in the list? Do you want a list of 2 loess results? Do you mean something like: `lapply(Data, function(d) loess(d[[2]]~d[[1]]))`?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Yes I would like to run a loess regression for each data frame in the list. This is an example with two data frames in the list, the two data frames are part of a time series which is segmented. Because I have to use it on many different time series and for each one a different number of data frames is obtained, I hoped in making a general loess regression function using the apply family so it can be applied to the list of data frames automatically.